# padding always pushes and increases the width of my container

Tags: css

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">ddgdfgdfgdfg</a></li>
<li><a href="">ddgdfgdfgdfgsdfdsfdsf</a></li>
<li><a href="">ddgdfg</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

li{width:120px; padding-left:10px;}

What I get is a 10px padding on the left, but it pushes the text beyond the 120px boundaries and makes it a 130px wide container. Ideally I want 10px padding on both sides, which leaves me 100px for the text link. And I want that text to wrap and push down. But that's not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Padding is always added to the width of the box in the W3C box model. Either dont specify a width or set the width to desired-width - padding. Additionally as Sandeep has shown in his answer you may need to specifically set the word-wrap to break for long continuous strings.

Answer (score 1):

write:

```
li{
 width:100px;
 padding:0 10px;
 word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

padding & border always adding width to the element.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following to your CSS part.

width:200px;

change the value 100px to whatever size you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).